# How to set contents of a BootStrap Input Group using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

Below is an example of Bootstrap Code to create a input-group.  How can I use jQuery to set the contents of the input-group using the id?

```
<div class = "container">
<div class = "input-group-addon">Your name</span>
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputField" placeholder="Full Name">
</div><br>
```

Also, is there a way I can make the input-group not editable.  I want to use it to display read-only text.

$("inputField").???? <-- What goes here??

Thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

```
$("#inputField").attr('readonly',true).val('myValue')
```

if you have access to the html put directly readonly="readonly" as attribute of input.
you can put value directly  in HTML with the value attribute.
ps: dont forget the "#"

Answer (score 1):

```
$('#inputField').val('the value');
```